# Filesystemwatcher on a folder and getting the filename

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor several folders.
When it triggers the change event I want to get the filename of the changed file.
Since the watcher is monitoring the folder when I try using e.Name or e.FullPath I get the folder path.

Is there a way to get the filename?

Code:
Its an array of watchers.

```
watchers[_Idx] = new FileSystemWatcher();
watchers[_Idx].Path = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
watchers[_Idx].IncludeSubdirectories = true;
watchers[_Idx].NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | 
                          NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName | 
                          NotifyFilters.Size;
watchers[_Idx].Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(SyncThread);
watchers[_Idx].Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(SyncThread);
watchers[_Idx].Renamed +=new RenamedEventHandler(SyncThread);
watchers[_Idx].EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Comment: Please show the code that initializes the FileSystemWatcher and its properties

Comment: If you don't want to know about directory changes then remove NotifyFilters.DirectoryName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the filename from the event:

```
// Define the event handlers.
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
   Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
}

private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
    Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
}
```

Code snippet taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

Comment: I tried that before but kept getting the folder name. turns out after it first gave the events for all the folders and sub folders involved and then moved on to the files. thanks